# Capture executed commands from programs

Tags: linux, bash, strace

Is there a way to capture the commands executed by GUI programs ?
Or even simple bash scripts ?
Like the "history" command from bash but available on the whole system.

Comment: you can use strace to get the sytem calls that a particular program executes.

Answer (score 1):

A shell (e.g. bash) has `-x` option and you can see all the commands which are executed by a particular script. run `sh -x <your_script` and see the output. You also can temporarily turn on/off this logging by issuing `set +x`, `set -x` inside a script.

regarding GUI programs, the answer depends on your needs, what kind of activity you'd like to log. You can use `strace` as suggested in the comments, and filter out `exec*` calls. But likely you assume something else since most  activities of a GUI program are performed w/o executing external programs.

Comment: For example : I use lxpanel with a "minimize all windows" button. I would like to capture the command executed by it when i click on it.
(I used " sudo strace -p 2248 -f 2>&1 | nl") to track the lxpanel process (PID 2248) and child ?!
But i don't have any exec there just that kind of stuff :

Comment: Maybe lxpanel is not launching the exec, any way to track "init" or every processes ? "sudo strace -f -p 1" don't do the trick

Comment: Huh. Any question being correctly asked almost immediately leads to an answer. Managing windows in X Window System is performed by sending appropriate messages (usually via X11 C API), that's why you see those syscalls. You could use `ltrace` to track _library_ calls, but it'd better to just look at simple examples and sources. Take a look at [wmctrl](https://sites.google.com/site/tstyblo//wmctrl) which is essentially a tool to manage windows from command line, which sources (`main.c`) besides regular application stuff like processing command line arguments is appropriate pure X11 calls